# Email notifications of item expiration on K2 (Joomla)

Tags: notifications, joomla, k2

Is there anyway to email the author of the item/article about the upcoming expiry of an item?

Comment: Please ask all Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  Your question contains no proof of effort/research and may be downvoted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.